# Inconsistent INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE error

Tags: windows, boot, windows-11, event-log

There is a weird type of error occasionally occurring on my device (today and the last time before, 1 week ago). After pressing the power button of my notebook (specs below) Windows (version below) bluescreens and reports the error INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE together with a mini-QR-code.

This error usually means, that there is some kind of issue with the boot-partition of Windows or with the storage device itself, which would prevent OS startup for good, until the issue is fixed.
But weirdly enough, after restarting the device, Windows starts up regularly with no signs of the issue whatsoever.

CHKDSK didn't reveal any malfunctions within the file system. Also, the Windows event log didn't show anything eye-catching.

I sadly don't have too many ideas of how to react to that.
Could this be a random malfunction due to outer influence? Or should I further investigate that, and if yes, how.

---

I am running Windows 11 Pro 21H2 B22000.493 on a barely one year old HP Spectre x360 15-eb0785ng

EDIT:
The notebook is using the Intel Optane(R) technology, which basically consists out of two NVMe SSDs in a RAID configuration.

Comment: I have had this problem due to not enough timeout in the firmware to allow my HDD to spin up (in the HDD days).  This can sometimes be fixed in the firmware.  Although, I doubt that this is your problem.. I have had this problem due to a bad cable.  I have had this problem due to an intermittent failing drive.  I have had this problem from a bad SATA slot.

Comment: Exactly this ^^^ Check all possibilities and, of course, start by updating UEFI.

Comment: Check the SMART data of the boot disk. Also check the Event Viewer for interesting messages.

Comment: @harrymc With "event log" i meant the Win Event Viewer. Nothing too concerning in there. Most of the stuff has to do with COM port issues which are related to me attaching microcontrollers to my USB

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Since I don't have a HDD this can't be the problem. My boot device is built in the M.2 formfactor + utilizes NVMe and thus directly plugges into a PCIe slot. So cable and SATA issues are also out of the way. I extracted the drive and first looked at it with SSD-Z and then let Dexter and HP Diagnostics run some scans to test it for any errors. The drive seems fine too.

Comment: No HDD? Using M.2?  This certainly rules many thing out. :)  In this case, could it be the contacts for the M.2 or even the M.2 itself?  I would lean toward the M.2 itself since it works after the first try.  I would still look in the firmware options and see if you can add a timeout for the drive.  The firmware might still offer this option.  It would be worth a try.

Comment: Since common diagnostics Software shows that the drive itself is ok and I see no obvious damage to the connector, the only thing left to do is to check the PCIe socket itself, but sadly I have no idea how that should work.